# how to inject API Key in Angular application using HTTP interceptor

Tags: angular, api-key

my backend service use Api key as an authentification type so when i use postman it gave me the hand to pass my Api Key and it works fine . but when i try to do the same using angular i don't find where to pass my API Key . 
here is my code angular

```
 intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {[enter image description here][1]
    request = request.clone({
      setHeaders: {
        Authorization: // pass api key here 
      }
return next.handle(request);
    });
```

Comment: There are lot of guides out there for your requirement. One such is https://medium.com/@ryanchenkie_40935/angular-authentication-using-the-http-client-and-http-interceptors-2f9d1540eb8

Comment: thanks, but I need to do for example Authorization: Api Key <credentials> ,such as basic authentication Authorization: Basic <credentials> ,but angular generate errors

Answer (score 0):

can you try this :

```
intercept(request: HttpRequest < any >, next: HttpHandler): Observable < HttpEvent < any >> {
    request = request.clone({
        headers: {
            Authorization: request.headers.set('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + token),
        }
    });
    return next.handle(request);
}
```